# PHP - Forced download causing 404 file not found errors

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to make a php forced download script for my website for zip files. I know the file path is correct and the link the script generates goes back to the file itself, but using the script the file is not found and without error checking it downloads a corrupt file. my code is as below.

```
<?php

session_start();

    $file='http://www.myurlgoeshere/'.$_SESSION['FilePath'];

    if (headers_sent()) {
        echo 'HTTP header already sent';
    } else {
        if (!is_file($file)) {
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
            echo 'File not found - '.$file;
        } else if (!is_readable($file)) {
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 403 Forbidden');
            echo 'File not readable';
        } else {
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
            header("Content-Type: application/zip");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
            header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($file)."\"");
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }
    }
?>
```

im getting the 404 not found although the link echod from $file works directly.

Am i doing something wrong or is it a psosible server side issue?

Cheers,

Dylan

Comment: use `http_response_code(404);` / `http_response_code(403)` , let http_response_code take care of the details, that's why it exists!

Answer (score 2):

The path to your file at the moment is:

```
$file='http://www.myurlgoeshere/'.$_SESSION['FilePath'];
```

When in actual fact it should be the path to the file on the server. So for example:

```
$file='/var/www/html/domain.com/public_html/downloads/file_to_download.zip';
```